# JMeter POST request is returning 200 OK instead of 302 (redirect)

Tags: jmeter

I'm attempting to login to a website that uses IdentityServer with JMeter but am getting stuck at the point where I post my credentials.

If I inspect the request via fiddler, I can see that it returns a 302 with a redirect, however when I attempt to post the same request in JMeter, I get a 200 with 'Error' in the html with no details.

This is my request in JMeter....

[image]

This is the request in Fiddler....

[image]

[image]

And this is the HTML response in JMeter (200 OK)...

[image]

And this is the Fiddler response...

[image]

And this is the HTML response in Fiddler, after the redirect...

[image]

I can confirm that my JMeter variables `${COOKIE_idsrv.xsrf}` and `${SignIn` are populated with the correct values.

Other points to note

- I have a **HTTP Cookie Manager**
- The **HTTP Manager** Referer headers are set correctly
- All requests are set to **Follow Redirects**
- I retrieve all embedded resources for each request

Does anybody know what could be the issue here?

Comment: I recommend that you add a http request default and configure it to point at fiddler, then compare between jmeter request and manual request on fiddler, there has to be some difference, find it and you will resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

In your POST request, why do you have "signin" parameter included?. You have already added "signin" as a query parameter and it appears to be redundant and not required for the actual POST body data. Fiddler does not have it in both the places. Please check.

Answer (score 0):

After much frustration it turned out the issue was due to `${COOKIE_idsrv.xsrf}` not containing the correct value for `idsrv.xsrf`. Once I changed this to pull it from a previous request it seemed to work okay.